# MVC ajax, no javascript fallback?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

With Ajax ActionLinks, what happens when Javascript is disabled? Does the .NET framework automatically take care of everything so do you specifically need to add support?

Does Webforms have something similiar to ajax actionlinks where it does not post the whole page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer to the second question, yes. Here is a tutorial on partial page post backs with asp.net webforms: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-partial-page-updates-with-asp-net-ajax

The answer to your first question should be very easy to answer with a simple test. Make an simple app, turn off javascript on your browser, find your answer.

Comment: That would take a world of translation to MVC, which doesn't have any of the web form controls described in the tutorial. But is does answer his second question about web forms.